# While loop in C++ ends, but doesn't continue onto the remaining statements

Tags: c++, arrays, class, while-loop, tic-tac-toe

This is the while loop that I am working with for a TicTacToe game I am trying to make,

```
while (result == 0)
{
    game.player_move();
    result = game.check_draw();
    game.computer_move();
} 

if (result == 1)
    cout << "Tie.";
```

and these are the conditions for `game.check_draw()`.

```
int TicTacToe::check_draw()
{
    if (move_count == 9)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Furthermore, this code does work the way that I want it to work. X is set with a value of 88 and 0 is set with a value of 79. Both the user and computer move functions increment the `move_count` value by one like this:

```
void TicTacToe::player_move()
{
    int position;

    draw_table();
    cout << endl << "Pick position[1-9]: ";
    cin >> position;

    while (pos[position - 1] == 79 || pos[position - 1] == 88)
    {
        system("CLS");
        draw_table();
        cout << endl << "Position taken.";
        Sleep(500);
        system("CLS");
        draw_table();
        cout << endl << "Pick position[1-9]: ";
        cin >> position;
        system("CLS");
    }

    position[pos - 1] = 88;
    move_count++; // <-------------
    system("CLS");
}
```

and

```
void TicTacToe::computer_move()
{
    int position;

    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    position = (rand() % 9) + 1;

    while (pos[position - 1] == 79 || pos[position - 1] == 88)
        position = (rand() % 9) + 1;

    position[pos - 1] = 79;
    move_count++; // <-------------
```

}

Since the player goes first, after the 9th turn the `move_count` is set to 9. Then the program continues onto the next statement.

```
if (result == 1)
    cout << "Tie.";
```

This code works perfectly, but **ONLY** if the following code from `game.computer_move()` is removed,

```
while (pos[position - 1] == 79 || pos[position - 1] == 88)
     position = (rand() % 9) + 1;
```

when this code is removed, the while loop ends and it continues onto the next if statement. However, when I add this code it does end the while loop but doesn't continue onto the if statement and displays a blinking cursor thing. All this code does, is check an array to see if X a.k.a (88) or O a.k.a (79) have already been placed in the position where 0 is to be placed.

I am profoundly confused because this doesn't affect the `move_count` at all, and furthermore after the 9th player move the `move_count` is set to 9 which means that the loop should terminate correctly and not even move onto `game.computer_move()`?

My understanding is that once the while condition is not met, the rest of the code in the while loop is ignored and the loop should end.

I have done a

```
cout << game.move_count;
```

in the loop, right before `game.check_draw()` to check if it has a value of 9 and indeed it does.

Also, a side comment. Is my code readable? Are there any glaring issues with it?

I can post the entirety of the code if requested and thank you for any replies in advance.

Comment: My "optimization" approach: `int TicTacToe::check_draw() { return move_count == 9; }` behaves _exactly_ like your original version.

Comment: To make your code more readable (I wondered about `79` and `88` but didn't dig deeper): Why not using `'X'` and `'O'` instead? [Character constants](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant) might be used in (nearly) any place like integer constants.

Comment: @Scheff could you elaborate on this? essentially what i did was create an array: int pos[9] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }; so that I could easily display a TicTacToe table with numbers in each box so the user could easily pick which box to play. Then if that box is equal to 79 or 88 then that array cell is displayed with a (char). Ex: 
 if (pos[0] == 1)
  cout << pos[0];
 else
  cout << (char)pos[0];

Comment: You didn't expose your array declaration but anyhow - this is true for `char pos[]` as well as `int pos[]`: If you want to compare an element whether it stores `'X'`, you can do simply `pos[i] == 'X'`. This is equivalent with `pos[i] == 88` as `'X'` is the character constant for ASCII 88 and thus represents the same value. (If you wouldn't use ASCII but something else (e.g. EBCDIC) (what I really don't believe) then `pos[i] == 88` might be broken but `pos[i] == 'X'` would even work with EBCDIC.)

Comment: I just found `position[pos - 1] = 79;` in `TicTacToe::computer_move()` which is probably a "swap mistake". You probably intended to write `pos[position - 1] = 79;` The funny fact is that both works equally: `position[pos - 1]` is the same as `*(position + pos - 1)`. `pos[position - 1]` is the same as `*(pos + position - 1)`. So, finally it addresses the same element. (but it made my eyes stumbling) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *My understanding is that once the while condition is not met, the rest of the code in the while loop is ignored and the loop should end.*

This is incorrect. The `while` loop only checks to see if the condition is met before the next iteration (At the end) of the loop. If the condition isn't met in the middle of the loop, it will continue until the end of the current iteration of the loop, and then break out of the loop. If you wish to end the loop immediately once a condition is met you can use a [break](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break) statement to break out of the loop.

From the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while):

> This expression is evaluated before each iteration, and if it yields false, the loop is exited.

Comment: For beginners, it might be useful to see their code in flowchart form, e.g. https://code2flow.com/5yl5gD.code.png  (It's not how I would have laid out the flowchart, but Code2Flow was free and fast)

Comment: @GBlodgett thank you so much, the code works perfectly now. I was aware of a break statement, but as I was taught by my college professor it only applies to switch statements...